# Java, getting button name that called a function

Tags: java, button, get, action, filenames

I just started a little java roulette game project and I need some help.
This is what my program looks like:

```
private void jToggleButton*(buttons 0 - 36)* {
ButtonFunction();
}
public static int ButtonAction() {
```

here i would like to get the name of the button that called this action so for example jToggleButton11, so i can use it
    }

how can i do this?

Comment: in your actionPerformed, get the source of the event.

Answer (score 0):

When you define your buttons, you will want something like this (for each button);

```
jToggleButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        buttonActions(1, e);
    }
});
```

This code passes `1` to `buttonActions`, you could similarly pass enums that identify each button or the actual button objects.

You will also need to give your `buttonActions` method a prototype like;

```
public static int buttonActions(int buttonId, ActionEvent e);
```

The other method would be to only pass the `ActionEvent` object, and to detect the buttons based on the [`getActionCommand()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand()) method, this would require you to detect the pressed buttons value(?) in `buttonActions`.